# Jquery append right after the opening div

Tags: jquery, append

I´ve got a code, that should create two elements into a div, but the created elements should be placed right after the opening div.

It shoould look like this:

### HTML result

```
<div id="sidebar_right">
    <div class="inside_sidebar">
    <div class="ce_text download" style="border: 1px solid Red">
<div class="text1">hello stackoverflow 1</div>
<div class="text2">hello stackoverflow 2</div>
        <p>This text is surrounded by a DIV tag whose id is "targetDIV".</p>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### Code

```
$("<div>hello stackoverflow </div>").appendTo("#sidebar_right.ce_text.download");
```

### Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/5b4xtoqh/1/

Can you guys help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/5b4xtoqh/5/)**

use `.prepend()`

js

```
$(".ce_text").prepend("<div>hello stackoverflow </div>");
```

Refer : [.prepend documentation on jquery.com](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/5b4xtoqh/5/)

Answer (score 1):

You need a space between `#sidebar_right` and the classes, because the classes belong to a descendant, not the same element.

Also, if you want `hello stackoverflow` to be added before the paragraph, you need to use `prepend`, not `append`. Append adds the new element at the end, prepend adds it at the beginning.

```
$("<div>hello stackoverflow </div>").prependTo("#sidebar_right .ce_text.download");
```

[Corrected fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/5b4xtoqh/4/)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$("#some_element").appendTo( $("#sidebar_right .ce_text.download") );
```

Answer (score 0):

use a `space` here and use `.prependTo` for placing new elem at the top index in the target div:

```
.prependTo("#sidebar_right .ce_text.download");
//------------------------^----------here
```

Answer (score 0):

You have errors with your selectors.
Try this jQuery code:

```
$("<div>hello stackoverflow </div>").appendTo("#sidebar_right .download");
```

Answer (score 0):

your jquery

```
$("<div>hello stackoverflow </div>").appendTo("#sidebar_right .ce_text");
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Amit12x/5b4xtoqh/7/)